# How to avoid pop-up of *Async Shell Command* buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, asynchronous, dired

My `~/.emacs` contains the following settings for opening certain files with certain applications (Ubuntu 12.10; Emacs 24):

```
(setq dired-guess-shell-alist-user
      '(("\\.pdf\\'" "okular ? &")
    ("\\.djvu\\'" "okular ? &")
        ("\\.mp3\\'" "vlc ? &")
    ("\\.mp4\\'" "vlc ? &")
    ))
```

When I navigate to a .pdf in `dired-mode` and hit `!`, it opens the .pdf in Okular, but the dired-buffer is split into two parts, the second one now being a useless `*Async Shell Command*` buffer containing content like

```
okular(25393)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(25393)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(25393)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(25393)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
```

How can I prevent this buffer from being opened? (except for, maybe, if there was an error and this information is useful).

I found related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915314/emacs-automatically-close-async-output-buffers-on-command-completion) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679930/how-to-automatically-remove-or-prevent-popping-up-async-shell-command-in-ema), but they seem to deal with specific commands executed asynchronously, instead of the `*Async Shell Command*` in general (if possible, I would like to change the behaviour in general for asynchronous processes, not only for certain file types)

Comment: Take a look at the actual functions inside the source of `.../lisp/simple.el` -- i.e., `defun shell-command` and `defun async-shell-command`.  You can even create your own custom functions and/or use `defalias`.  When using `start-process`, the second argument is the output buffer name -- using `nil` for the second argument prevents an output buffer from being created.  You can use `set-process-sentinel` in conjunction with `start-process`.

Comment: The doc string of `async-shell-command` states:  `... In Elisp, you will often be better served by calling 'start-process' directly, since it offers more control and does not impose the use of a
shell (with its need to quote arguments).`

Answer (score 26):

Found this [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.emacs.help/TNqE7R7mULk/ZV6VaeIiOHQJ):

```
(call-process-shell-command "okular&" nil 0)
```

Works for me. No stderr gobbledygook.

Comment: Actually this was the only answer that indeed full works: no log at messages and no weird popups.

Comment: Could anyone elaborate on that? Do I put this function inside `dired-guess-shell-alist-user`? How? I just tried: `(add-to-list 'dired-guess-shell-alist-user '("\\.pdf$" (call-process-shell-command "evince" nil 0)))`, and it does not work - it opens evince, but not the file at point.

Answer (score 14):

The question was asked in 2012, and at the time of my writing, the most recent answer is dated 2015. Now, in 2017, I can say that the answer is simple:

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
  (cons "\\*Async Shell Command\\*.*" (cons #'display-buffer-no-window nil)))
```

Comment: This still creates a buffer, but at least it doesn't pop into view and take up half of the screen. I'm sticking to this one, it's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 6):

I am piggybacking off of user1404316's answer, but here is another generic way to achieve the desired outcome.

```
(defun async-shell-command-no-window
    (command)
  (interactive)
  (let
      ((display-buffer-alist
        (list
         (cons
          "\\*Async Shell Command\\*.*"
          (cons #'display-buffer-no-window nil)))))
    (async-shell-command
     command)))
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer! Avoids the buffer only for specific commands. Used it to code the command that creates the TAGS file `(defun mktags-here () (interactive) ... (async-shell-command (message (format "ctags -e -R ."))))`.

Comment: call-process-shell-command and adding an & to the command  was the simplest for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about doing it for asynchronous processes in general, but for anything that goes through `async-shell-command`, this should work:

```
    (defadvice async-shell-command (around hide-async-windows activate)
       (save-window-excursion
          ad-do-it))
```

Comment: But then you are forcing all uses of `async-shell-command` to lose the buffer.  I'd think that would be overkill; there will certainly be situations where you do want to see the output.  Changing the advice to add a parameter which specifies whether or not to do `save-window-excursion` should not be too hard, but then why use advice in the first place; use a simple wrapper function instead.

Comment: ... I do realize OP asked for a fix to `async-shell-command` specifically, but the caveats for messing with it should be emphasized.

Comment: This did not work for me. I still get the Async Shell Command buffer.

Comment: That's because `async-shell-command` calls `shell-command` to do its magic.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no good way to avoid this buffer as it's called directly by 'shell-command' function ('async-shell-command' is just a wrapper).

So, a much better way is to replace 'async-shell-command' with '[start-process](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html#Asynchronous-Processes)'.
You should start process with '[set-process-sentinel](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html#Sentinels)' to detect the moment when process emits 'exit signal. Then kill process.

Comment: start-process is fundamentally different in that you cant pass a SHELL command that executes in the context of the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more complicated incantation should get you what you want.  Just use a shell command like:  `(okular ? >& /dev/null &)`.

I haven't tested this with okular, but I can do <kbd>M-!</kbd> `((echo foo; sleep 10; echo bar) >& /dev/null &)` and Emacs returns immediately without creating a new buffer.

Comment: Nice. However, the *Async Shell Command* buffer still pops up (just empty now). If I try your `M-! ...` command, I get "shell command succeeded with no output"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, using this method:

```
;list of programs, corresponding to extensions
(setq alist-programs
      '(("pdf" ."okular")
        ("djvu" . "okular")
        ("mp3" . "xmms")))

(defun my-run-async-command (command file)
  "Run a command COMMAND on the file asynchronously.
   No buffers are created"
  (interactive
   (let ((file (car (dired-get-marked-files t current-prefix-arg))))
     (list
      ;last element of alist-programs, contains COMMAND
      (cdr
       (assoc
        (file-name-extension file)
        alist-programs))
      file)))
  ;begin of function body
  (if command ;command if not nil?
      (start-process "command" nil command file)
    )
)

;attach function to <f2> key
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
    (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<f2>") 'my-run-async-command)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions to use start-process are ok if he is running a distinct program on the path of course. But if you want run some shell command in a specific directory (eg your project directory) then simply quell the popup - you frequently want the buffer but just dont want it jumping up in your face. eg I run a webserver and I want to see the output, just not now...

```elisp
  (use-package php-mode
    :config
    (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
    (cons "\\*Symfony Web Server\\*.*" (cons #'display-buffer-no-window nil)))
    (defun php-mode-webserver-hook ()
      (if (projectile-project-root) (let ((default-directory (projectile-project-root)))
        (unless (get-buffer "*Symfony Web Server*" )
          (async-shell-command "bin/console server:run" "*Symfony Web Server*")))))
    :hook (php-mode . php-mode-webserver-hook))
```